# Comparing path strings against list of rules

Tags: efficiency, comparison, loops

I am trying to find a way to enhance a filtering algorithm. I am developing a backup software that enables users to specify custom filters to exclude unwanted files/directories. 
Currently when trying to check if a file should be taken into backup, the path of the file is compared against a list of rules.

Each rule is specific to a single path (file or directory) and the path of the file is compared in a way similar to this:

Lets assume this is our rule structure

```
[Rule]
Path = "C:\Windows\"
Exclude = TRUE
```

And I compare the file path I got with the rule path by the length of the rule path.

Now, this works fine and I haven't had an issue with it but my issue is that I do not have a limit on the number of rules a user can add to the system. He can add as many rules as he likes and here is my problem.

The more rules a user adds means more iterations for each file against the rules set.

What is a good practice to do such thing?

Answer (score 3):

One way to improve this is to build a tree structure out of the path components.

So if he adds `c:\Windows\system32` and `c:\Windows\temp` and your input path is `c:\users\serpent` then you can happily skip both rules with a single check.

As your rule set gets bigger, this approach can reduce the amount of checking considerably. Some collections can do this for you automatically (a c++ stl map for example), you add all your paths and the collection stores them in a tree structure based on the strings.

Edit:

imagine you're looking for a taxi in the phone directory. Do you: start at the beginning and work your way through, comparing you input requirement of a taxi against the aardvark trainers, then the abacus sellers, etc; or do you skip to the T section, then skip to the Taxi subsection and then look through the list of taxi companies?

This is the same principle - if you split your rule paths into their components, then an input directory that is (in our examples) not inside the Windows root directory can be skipped completely - there's no need to check against c:\Windows\temp because you've ruled out *all* c:\Windows\*everything* rules.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how a map or tree can help me with this. not that I am comparing files agains a set of files and/or directories. For example, if the input path is lets say `c:\Windows\temp\somedirectoy\somefile` and the rule is `c:\Windows\temp` how will I check this since the file path nor its immediate parent is present in the collection.

Comment: c:\Windows\temp marks the path from the root. Every subpath is ruled out. Since c:\Windows\temp\somedirectoy is a subpath it is ruled out. You have to construct two pathobjects and do the comparison.

Comment: @RedSerpent You could store the rules in a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). If the input path is `C:\Windows\Temp\somedirectory\somefile` you'd traverse the trie going down the `C:` branch, then the `Windows` branch, and finally the `Temp` branch (where presumably the search ends, if there's no rules for subdirectories of `Temp`). Depending on how rule precedence works you may look at the rules at each node along the way (if e.g. the rules for `C:`, `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\Temp` stack) or look at only the rules at the end (if the rules for `C:\Windows\Temp` take precedence.).